# Im trying to encode all data from a table in JSON but there is no result

Tags: php, mysql, json

Here is the webpage in question

http://liamure.xyz/rsk/getdata.php

Here is the database
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu0lv.png)

And here is the SQL code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'Password', 'database');
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed Connection" . mysqli_connect_errno();
}
else
{
    $sth = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM quotes");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    echo"1";
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);

}

?>
```

When the webpage is run all that gets returned is "[]" (You can see this by clicking the URL above)

Comment: Just for clarity, how many rows are in the quotes table?

Comment: 3 rows [Screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu0lv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of `mysqli_query` function is the connection link object:

```
$sth = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM quotes");
```